# Send live audio from UDP socket in python server to javascript client

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket, udp

I'm receiving radio messages (audio) in a UDP socket. The port is opened when audio appears, and it's being closed when audio disappears. I know the audio appears, because in a different UDP port I receive a json message with the event "initiated" and "down".

I want to send that live audio to the browser, I understand I need to use a websocket. How I can connect the UDP audio packets when those appears, and send it using a websocket?

The audio packets are raw 16-bit real samples at 8ksps.

Is it possible to use a flask API to receive audio packet from UDP, and send it as live audio to the browser?

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/socketio-examples/tree/master/audio) help (example that utilizes socketio to record audio from client to server).

Comment: @sqz I don't think so, that example writes an audio file. I want to redirect live audio stream from UDP to the front end.